Error con inyección de dependencias en android: error: [Hilt] Unsupported metadata version
Estoy aprendiendo a usar dagger hilt en un proyecto con jetpack compose, sin embargo me está marcando el siguiente error.
    [Hilt]
  Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0

Ya revisé la documentación en android developers para implementar dagger hilt, sin embargo no logro encontrar el error. Anexo el código de mis clases build gradle:
build.gradle.kts (Project)
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
 plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44" apply false
}

build.gradle.kts (Module:App)
            plugins {
        alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
        alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
        id("kotlin-kapt")
        id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
    }
    
    android {
        namespace = "com.androidavanzado.jetpackcomposeinstagram"
        compileSdk = 34
    .
.

        buildTypes {
            release {
                isMinifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),"proguard-rules.pro")
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
        buildFeatures {
            compose = true
        }
        composeOptions {
            kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
        }
        packaging {
            resources {
                excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
            }
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation(libs.androidx.material3.android)
        val compose_version = "1.0.1"
        implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
        implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version")
        implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version")
        implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version")
        implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version")
        implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1")
        implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.2.1")
    
        implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
        implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
    
        implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1")
        testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
        androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3")
        androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0")
        androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version")
        implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version")
    
        implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")
        kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")
    }
    
    // Allow references to generated code
    kapt {
        correctErrorTypes = true
    }

gradle.properties:
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
android.useAndroidX=true
kotlin.code.style=official
kotlin.version = 1.8.0

Me podrían ayudar resolver o explicarme como puedo modificar la versión de kotlin que debe usar el proyecto para configurarlo.

No nos estás mostrando nada sobre tu configuración de Kotlin. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

En el archivo build.gradle(app) tiene: kotlinOptions {
jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

El mensaje :

[Hilt]   Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin
version is >= 1.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported
metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0

Indica que la versión de Kotlin que está usando tu proyecto y la que requiere alguna de tus dependencias en el proyecto no son compatibles, en este caso te indica que la dependencia es precisamente: Dagger Hilt.
Tienes definida la versión 2.44 :
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")

Cambia la versión de Kotlin a una versión mayor, probablemente tu proyecto es antiguo, entonces dentro del archivo gradle.properties define una versión apropiada, por ejemplo podrías definir la versión:
kotlin.version=1.8.0

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details
En las nuevas versiones de proyectos, la versión de Kotlin se define en el archivo libs.versions.toml :


ya agregué la etiqueta kotlin version en gradle.properties pero marca el mismo error ¿Hay forma de valida la versión de java que usa cada librería?

El problema es de Kotlin con Hilt, que versión de Kotlin tienes definido en tu proyecto inicialmente?

Validando el proyecto me di cuenta que el archivo libs.version.toml estaba utilizando kotlin="1.9.0" lo cambié a la versión 1.8.0 que es la misma versión de kotlin que marca build.gradle, anexo fotos de como quedó.


